# Unable to generate allure report in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, allure

getting the following error.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bteO.png) is also attached.
basically `.bat` is not getting generated.

```
ERROR: Step ‘Allure Report’ aborted due to exception: 
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename C:\Users\dell\.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure2\allure-2.4.1 to C:\Users\dell\.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure2\allure-2.4.1.__rename
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Comment: Permissions to access the file in the error?

Answer (score 0):

Now its working.

There is problem in allure command installation.

> Maven central installer is giving error

Tried by giving link in jenkins global tool configuration and its working
Link : https://bintray.com/qameta/generic/download_file?file_path=io%2Fqameta%2Fallure%2Fallure%2F2.4.1%2Fallure-2.4.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when configured with the latest version of Maven under Jenkins->Global Tool Configurations->Allure Commandline. Once i downgraded the Maven version I was able to generate allure reports successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was enough to delete allure-jenkins plugin from the list of plugins in Jenkins.

Comment: Hey, I believe you are getting downvotes because you are more conversational than giving explicit instructions.